# Initialize all properties of a proxy in Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I´m using Spring JpaRepository to access the database. My goal is to create a method which finds one entity and fully initializes it. Currently I´m doing it like that:

```
Hibernate.initialize(business.getCollectionA());
Hibernate.initialize(business.getCollectionB());
Hibernate.initialize(business.getCollectionC());
```

So I search for a method which initializes all collections at once like that:

```
Hibernate.initializeAll(business);
```

Comment: So, what is your question?

Comment: There is no method Hibernate.initializeAll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As such `Hibernate` or `JPA` does not provide any utility to initialize all `lazy properties` for the entity.

You need to write your `recursive` logic, using Java `Reflection` to traverse the tree and initialize the objects.

You can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11445099/hibernate-recursive-initialization) more or less what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can mark you collection properties as `FetchType.EAGER` to make them loaded automatically as soon as the Entity is loaded.

e.g.

```
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
private Set collectionA;
```

Add this fetchtype to any collection you want "initialized". Note that this kills performance, but it has the same effect as invoking initialize on each collection.

Comment: That is what I want to avoid

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
    import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
    import org.hibernate.metadata.ClassMetadata;
    import org.hibernate.type.CollectionType;
    import org.hibernate.type.Type;

    // you should already have these somewhere:
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = ...
    Session session = ...
    MyEntity myEntity = ...

    // this fetches all collections by inspecting the Hibernate Metadata.
    ClassMetadata classMetadata = sessionFactory.getClassMetadata(MyEntity.class);
    String[] propertyNames = classMetadata.getPropertyNames();
    for (String name : propertyNames)
    {
        Object propertyValue = classMetadata.getPropertyValue(myEntity, name, EntityMode.POJO);
        Type propertyType = classMetadata.getPropertyType(name);
        if (propertyValue != null && propertyType instanceof CollectionType)
        {
            CollectionType s = (CollectionType) propertyType;
            s.getElementsIterator(propertyValue, session);   // this triggers the loading of the data
        }
    }
```