# Handle 'recursive' entities retrieval from Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I would like to know what is best practice, or the usual approach, when dealing with the retrieval of potentially very large Entities originating from the database via Hibernate.

Consider the following POJOs:

```
class Movie implements Serializable {
    @Id 
    private long id;

    private String title;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="acted_movies")
    private Set<Person> cast;
}    

class Person implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private long id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "Person_Movie_Actor", 
         joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "person_id") }, 
         inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "movie_id") })
    private Set<Movie> acted_movies;
}
```

Retrieving information from the database is performed as follows:

```
@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

protected Session getSession() {
    return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
}

public Movie findById(long id) {
    Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(Movie.class);
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("id", id));
    return (Movie) criteria.uniqueResult();
}
```

Due to the recursive nature of their attributes, I'm worried about the size of the returned objects: A movie has a set of actors, and each have participated in movies, and so forth ...

Of course, I can write my own custom SQL queries, so that I only return the ID of the involved Persons rather than the object for instance. However, this requires to define new classes, and subsequent database update may become cumbersome...

Any thoughts on how to easily manage this?

Further, it seems that Converters or Mappers are not really what I need here since I would still need to load the full objects in memory..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this is directly handled by Hibernate. One can specify `FetchType.LAZY` as the fetch type to use for loading your entities, this will not load the relationships (OneToOne, etc).

Then one can explicitly call `Hibernate.initialize(..)` to explicitly load the relationships.

It is also worth noting that `Hibernate.initialize(..)` does not recursively inits all members. See this SO [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11445099/hibernate-recursive-initialization) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

You can get only ids without creating any additional classes.

Following is a way to get person ids for a movie.

```
//em is entity manager
TypedQuery<Long> query = em.createQuery(
  "SELECT m.cast.id FROM Movie AS m where m.id=:movieId", Long.class);
query.setParameter("movieId",1l);
List<Long> personIds = query.getResultList();
```